# iOS JSON Search blocking UI

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, nsjsonserialization

I want to search the AppStore based on what a user types into search.

I have set up the following code to do this, which will amend the search on each character being entered to narrow the search.

However, as there is a request made as every character entered and these can take time to return, the UI can become unresponsive.

I would like to a) understand how I can stop the UI becoming unresponsive (I fear I am bringing the running back onto the main thread with performselectoronmainthread?), and b) would it be prudent to cancel the previous lookup as each character is entered, thus using the new narrower search, and if so how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have tried the suggestion as made by Emilie Lessard, and whilst I can see the logic, I am unable to get this to benefit the app. See response below.

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        jsonResults = nil;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        jsonResults = nil;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSURL *searchUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@&country=gb&entity=software",text]];
         dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
         NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:searchUrl];
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
         withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
         });
    }
}


-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData{
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    jsonResults = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dispatch_async()`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Do the computing-research

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do UI update here
    });
});
```

By using a global queue, the UI of your app won't get blocked. Once all info has been computed/received, it is MANDATORY that you go back to the main thread (by using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` for all UI updates or you'll end up with *hard-to-debug* crashes.

Comment: I have just tried this in the 'else' above, and put the 'fetcheddata' code in there direct, with only the table reload on the main queue, and it is still blocking, but also crashing randomly! Where would you expect to place the code? I am thinking I need to cancel the last request with each new character entered, but may be wrong?

Comment: I realised that in my table I was calling another `NSData` to get the icon for each app, and it was this that was blocking the UI. I utilised the above code again there and the issue is now resolved. Many thanks to Emilie.